# How to add the first element of this nested array

Tags: javascript, multidimensional-array

I have this nested array

```
let thirarray = [
    [2, 3, 4],
    [5, 6, 7, 8],
    [9, 10],
];
```

and what I'm trying to do is add the first element of each array so basically add 2+5+9= 16
I know I can access each element like this

```
//this is how i can access the first element of each array
console.log(thirarray[0][0]);
console.log(thirarray[1][0]);
console.log(thirarray[2][0]);
```

I know I can access with a nested loop all the elements like this

```
let suminsidearrays = 0;

for (i = 0; i < thirarray.length; i++) {
    for (let j = 0; j < thirarray[i].length; j++) {
        console.log(thirarray[i][j]);
        suminsidearrays += thirarray[i][j];
        console.log(suminsidearrays);

    }
}
```

So my question is how can add the first element of each array?

Answer (score 0):

This will sum the first element in each array inside the main array.

```js
const array = [[2, 3, 4],[5, 6, 7, 8],[9, 10]]
let sum = array.reduce((a,c)=>a+c[0],0)
console.log(sum)
```

Update for new pattern requirement in the comment.

```js
const array = [[2, 3, 4],[5, 6, 7, 8],[9, 10, 11]]
let i = 0, sum = array.reduce((a,c)=>a+c[i++],0)
console.log(sum)
```

Comment: thanks a lot for helping me. Works great, can I ask you one more thing. Say I add number 11 to the last array and I try to add the numbers progressively like this 2+6+11 = 19. How can I achieve it? I am trying to understand how to add the elements in a static way and progressively as well.

Comment: @Cosmel What is the desired output?

Comment: the output I am looking for now is 19 which is adding 2 + 6 + 11 = 19 . The first element in the first array then numbers 6 which would be index position 1 in the second array and then 11 on the last array which should be index position 2.

Comment: @Cosmel What actually is the pattern here?

Comment: I see the pattern as increasing by 1 on each array. Your solution helped me to add not only the 1st element in each array but I was able to use it for the next index position as well as adding 3+6+10=19. What I would like to know is how to add now the first element and then adding 1 to the next index position. So I should have 2+6+11. Again adding the number 11 to the last array

Comment: @Cosmel Updated

Answer (score 0):

simplest way to do it

```js
let thirarray = [[2, 3, 4],[5, 6, 7, 8],[9, 10]];
var res=0
thirarray.forEach(a=>res+=a[0])
console.log(res)
```

Answer (score 0):

I just want to add that I was able to solve it using what I learned from @holydragon.
So this is what I did

```
let fourthrarray = [
    [20, 30, 40],
    [50, 60, 70, 80],
    [90, 100, 110, 120, 130],
];

let nextindexposition = 0;
let nextto = 0;
let sumeelsegundo = 0;

for (let i = 0; i < fourthrarray.length; i++) {
    //this will allow me to see the 1st index position from each array
    //i should expect to see 20,50,90
    sumeelsegundo = fourthrarray[i][0];
   //this will add the first index position of each array expected output will be 160
    sumeelsegundo += fourthrarray[i][0];
    console.log(sumeelsegundo);
   //in order to add the next index position from each array i used two variable
  //one that will store the result and the other one that will increase the index 
  //position by one on every iteration. this one will allow me to see the elements
 //that will be added. expected elements will be 20,60,110
    nextto = fourthrarray[i][nextindexposition++];
 //this will be adding the elements expected output expected output 190
    nextto += fourthrarray[i][nextindexposition++];
    console.log(nextto);

}
```

Just to clarify something this solution works for adding numbers, If I wanted to multiply I just had to change the starting value on the variable nextto from 0 to 1.